# SSH works in Windows Virtual Machine, but not on native Ubuntu machine

Tags: ssh, vpn, openconnect

I have to connect to a Linux server through a VPN for school. I am able to connect via Putty through my Windows Virtual Machine, and I can also connect to the VPN (Cisco AnyConnect), but I cannot connect on my native Ubuntu machine. The VPN is successful via my terminal, just not ssh.
I try to ping the server, and it just sits there. When I try to ssh into the server, I get "Connection Timed Out."

What is blocking me from connecting if I can do it on my VM? Any suggestions?

**Note**: I left actual names and IPs out.

Here is my output when connecting to the VPN:

```
christopher@HAL:~$ sudo openconnect -s /etc/vpnc/vpnc-script https://secureconnect.some_university.edu
[sudo] password for christopher: 
POST https://secureconnect.some_university.edu/
Attempting to connect to server xx.xx.xx.xx:443
SSL negotiation with secureconnect.some_university.edu
Connected to HTTPS on secureconnect.some_university.edu
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.0 302 Object Moved
GET https://secureconnect.some_university.edu/
Attempting to connect to server xx.xx.xx.xx:443
SSL negotiation with secureconnect.some_university.edu
Connected to HTTPS on secureconnect.some_university.edu
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.0 302 Object Moved
GET https://secureconnect.some_university.edu/+webvpn+/index.html
SSL negotiation with secureconnect.some_university.edu
Connected to HTTPS on secureconnect.some_university.edu
Please enter your username and password.
GROUP: [xxxxx]:xxxxx <-- leaving name out
Please enter your username and password.
Username:<my_username>
Password:xxxxxxxxx   
POST https://secureconnect.some_university.edu/+webvpn+/index.html
Got CONNECT response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
CSTP connected. DPD 30, Keepalive 20
/bin/sh: 1: /etc/vpnc/vpnc-script: not found
Script '/etc/vpnc/vpnc-script' returned error 127
/bin/sh: 1: /etc/vpnc/vpnc-script: not found
Script '/etc/vpnc/vpnc-script' returned error 127
Connected tun0 as 192.168.30.106, using SSL
Established DTLS connection (using GnuTLS). Ciphersuite (DTLS0.9)-(RSA)-(AES-256-CBC)-(SHA1).
```

Here is my attempt to ssh into the server once connected to the VPN:

```
christopher@HAL:~$ ssh -v xxxxxxx.some_university.edu
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for xxxxxxx.some_university.edu
debug1: Connecting to uisacad.uis.edu [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host xxxxxxx.some_university.edu port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Dang....no one knows...... Not even my instructor knows how to help me on this one, or tech support, so I'm kinda stuck. I can at least use my Virtual Machine in the mean time I guess. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was right in front of me the entire time! These lines here:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /etc/vpnc/vpnc-script: not found <-- realized it here
Script '/etc/vpnc/vpnc-script' returned error 127 
/bin/sh: 1: /etc/vpnc/vpnc-script: not found
Script '/etc/vpnc/vpnc-script' returned error 127
```

I ran "locate vpnc-script" and I discovered that for some reason it was in /usr/share/vpnc/ when I installed it. So, I did a mkdir /etc/vpnc and then moved everything inside /usr/share/vpnc over to there, changed proper permissions, and voila! It works! I ssh'd into the server and it connected immediately! This will make things so much easier because I was sick of using my virtual machine.